# How to run Codeigniter 4 without php spark serve

Tags: php, url, codeigniter-4, serve

I do not use "php spark serve" command every time. Is it possible to us that without cmd command? I searched and found something. They are saying that move files from public directory to htdocs and change

```
$pathsConfig = FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';
```

to

```
$pathsConfig = FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php';
```

but it does not work. By the way, my main location is htdocs/cms. And I changed base url in App.php like this

```
    public $baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/cms/';
```

and .env like this

```
app.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/cms/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set up a virtual host on your local machine.

## STEPS

*Based on a windows computer & xampp.*
*Assumes your main project directory is at `C:\xampp\htdocs\cms`*

1. Edit the file `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`, add the line below at the end and save. *You may need administrative privileges to change this file.*

```
127.0.0.1       local.cms
```

2. Edit the file `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`, add the lines below at the end and save.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin sinan-sankaya@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\public"
        ServerName local.cms

            <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
                 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                 AllowOverride All
                 Order allow,deny
                 Allow from all
                 Require all granted
            </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

3. Reset your `$pathsConfig` variable back to the default (`C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\public\index.php`).

```php
// ...
$pathsConfig = FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';
// ...
```

4. Change your `$baseURL` configuration. (`C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\app\Config\App.php`)

```php
// ...
    public $baseURL = "http://local.cms";
// ...
```

- If you make use of the `.env` file, configure that as well.

```
 app.baseURL = 'http://local.cms'
```

5. Restart the Apache webserver. *You may start the MySQL service as well if you haven't already and your app uses a database.*

[image]

6. Open your favourite web browser and search `http://local.cms`

Answer (score 0):

I am a Mac OS user. And I was using Xampp for Codeigniter. Now I tried Mamp, and it works. Thank you for the answers.